# Why am I not getting proper output in the C program?

Tags: c

I wrote a C program to register a user and login using the same username and password but I am getting `Username invalid/doesn't exist` message when trying to login. Any idea what I have been doing wrong in the following code? Also when I re-run the program I can't get the `Login Successfully` message. Even if I use the commented `fscanf()` function in the code I don't get the proper output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct database {
    char name[20];
    char email[30];
    char user[10];
    char pass[20];
} store;

int main() {
    int count, entries, choice;
    char username[10];
    char password[20];
    FILE *fptr;
    fptr = fopen("E:\\login.bin", "ab+");
    printf("Welcome to the user authentication program v1.2 .\n");
 Again:
    printf("\n1. Register\n");
    printf("2. Login\n");
    printf("3. Exit\n");
    printf("\nEnter your choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch(choice) {
      case 1:
        printf("\nEnter the number of users.\n");
        printf("Users = ");
        scanf("%d", &entries);
        for (count = 1; count <= entries; count++) {
            /*printf("\nEnter your email: ");
            scanf("%s", &store.email);
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", store.email);*/

            printf("\nEnter a username: ");
            scanf("%s", &store.user);
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", store.user);

            printf("\nEnter a password: ");
            scanf("%s", &store.pass);
            fprintf(fptr, "%s\n", store.pass);

            printf("\nRegistration successful.\n");

        }
        goto Again;
        break;

      case 2:
        printf("Enter your username: ");
        scanf("%s", &username);
        ///fscanf(fptr, "%s", &store.user);
        printf("Enter your password: ");
        scanf("%s", &password);
        ///fscanf(fptr, "%s", &store.pass);
        if (strcmp(username, store.user) == 0) {
            if (strcmp(password, store.pass) == 0) {
                printf("\nLogin Successful.\n");
            } else {
                printf("\nIncorrect password!\n");
            }
        } else {
            printf("\nUsername invalid/doesn't exist.\n");
        }
        break;

      case 3:
        exit(1);
        break;
    }
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

Comment: What are the return values of your `scanf()` calls?

Comment: The posted code won't compile. I get: Error (active) E0020 identifier "line" is undefined StackOverFlow d:\Repo\WIP\CTest\StackOverFlow\StackOverFlow\Source.c 48

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE].

Comment: If you add a `default` to your switch, with a `printf()` is it unexpectedly executed?

Comment: If I add a default in my switch, with a printf() then it isn't unexpectedly executed.

Comment: @Yunnosch what do you mean by the return values? and if you are talking about the values stored in file then the values are correctly stored.

Comment: I mean the return values. The values returned from calling a function, those which get returned by `return` statement from a function. Those which you ignore if you do not use something like `myInt=scanf(...)`. You do know what these value signify, don't you?

Comment: when I register using one user/pass and then select option 2 then it shows login successfully but when I close and re-run the program then it gives me "username ivalid/doesn't exist" message.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is incomplete. Your writing auth data to a file you never read. You should consider building an array of database records and iterating over each one when you are trying to find a match.

Learn to use your debugger. You would have noticed that only the last auth record created in `case 1` is lingering in `store` when you get to `case 2`. You also would have noticed that the `fscanf(fptr, "%s", &store.user)` was reading only one record.

Consider this program outline:

```
if exist authfile LoadAuth()
if user enter new auth data, update internal database, then write to file.
if user attempts login, create a temp record with their auth data and then 
iterate through the database, comparing that record to ones in the database.
  If not found, fail the login.
```

Comment: how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You read the login and password into a local structure and append the credentials to the file, but you never read the file to check against all the login/passwords in the database.

The program only works if you register a single user and log in immediately after. Furthermore you have no error handling, so invalid input can cause undefined behaviour in many places.

Comment: so what do i do to make a program to register multiple users and log in whenever i run the program?

Comment: Loop over reading the records into memory. You can probably read them all into an array or linked list. You should do that at the start of your program.

Comment: I looped over reading records but now it only accepts the first username and password stored in the file.

Comment: @user9901959: your program needs more work, there seems to be a bug in how you update the file with new registrations. Post your code in a new question.

Comment: i got my program to work by copying the entire file contents in an 2 dimensional array and then comparing it using strcmp()